# app fails to connect to parse backend

Tags: android, parse-platform

My app works perfectly fine when running it the first time. But when I leave it in the background and then resume it (couple of hours later), it does not connect to the parse backend anymore:

> ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-152 calls detatch() 09-21
>
> Error:
>   i/o failure: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
>   /66.209.11.33:80 timed out 09-21 12:19:12.632
>
> I/System.out﹕
>   ParseRequest.NETWORK_EXECUTOR-thread-153 calls detatch()

Any ideas why?

Comment: You ever figure out the answer to this question?